# Fetch join collections with criteria / filter

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to load entities and fetch join another entity.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->addSelect('be, becs');
$qb->from('MeMyBundle:Entity', 'be');
$qb->leftJoin('be.associations', 'becs');
$qb->andWhere('becs.attribute=:attribute');
$qb->setParameter('attribute', $filterAttribute);
```

The fetch join is necessary to avoid all these single SQL results later on.

On the other hand not using my filterAttribute (setting a where condition on the join) would result in expensively hydrating too many joined objects which I don't need.

But this leads to the fact that my result is empty when no matching joined entities are existing. But I need the matching ones or an empty collection.

How can I escape this trap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the 3rd and 4th parameters of the `leftJoin()` method.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->addSelect('be, becs');
$qb->from('MeMyBundle:Entity', 'be');
$qb->leftJoin('be.associations', 'becs', 'WITH', 'becs.attribute=:attribute');
$qb->setParameter('attribute', $filterAttribute);
```

See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods